# Excel with If statement that can have more than two outcomes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using this formula:
IF((AND(H11<>"",L11<>""),"Both",IF(AND(H11<>"",L11=""),"First"),IF(AND(H11="",L11<>""),"Second"))

I have two columns, if both columns are filled then write 'Both' in the 3rd column, if the first column is filled but the second is blank then label the 3rd column 'First', if the First column is blank and the second is filled then label the third column as 'Second'
What am I doing wrong here?
My error shows the following:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

THANKS!

Comment: Your parentheses are all over the place. Check where they begin and end...

Comment: try this `=IF(AND(H11<>"",L11<>""),"Both",IF(AND(H11<>"",L11=""),"First",IF(AND(H11="",L11<>""),"Second")))`

Comment: One thing you can try when troubleshooting formulas is to click in the edit bar. If you are using functions, click on each function to will show the syntax. If you click on each section of the syntax it will highlight the portion of the formula related to that argument. Particularly useful with If statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above your Parentheses are all over the place. You open some and close them at random places elsewhere. You really have to spend the time to step through complex statements like this and insure that you have your parentheses properly lined up.

I think this should work for you:

```
IF(AND(H11<>"",L11<>""),"Both",IF(AND(H11<>"",L11=""),"First",IF(AND(H11="",L11<>""),"Second")))
```

I like to use a program like Notepad++ that will highlight matching parentheses when you hover over one:

For instance, hovering over the second parentheses just before that first `AND()` you will see that the closing parentheses is WAY at the back of the statement. Surely that doesn't make sense since that first parentheses in the statement would have to occur after it.

[image]

When I get in a real pickle with nested parenthetical statements like this I like to rewrite it using new-lines and indentation. It highlights issues pretty quick:

```
IF(
    (
        AND(
            H11<>"",
            L11<>""
        ),
        "Both",
        IF(
            AND(
                H11<>"",
                L11=""
            ),
            "First"
        ),
        IF(
            AND(
                H11="",
                L11<>""
            ),
            "Second"
        )
    )
```

And you can see, again, that there is stuff that isn't where it belongs and at least one of the opening parentheses is lacking it's closing parentheses.

Comment: This worked! Thank you!! I'll start using Notepad++ for these issues then. The new-line indentations is a smart trick too.

Answer (score 0):

The structure should be like the following. The original formula has several errors, 2nd and 3rd IF do not have valuse for false

```
IF(
   (AND(H11<>"",L11<>""),
   "Both",
   IF(
       AND(H11<>"",L11=""),
       "First",
       IF(
           AND(H11="",L11<>""),
           "Second",
           "none"
        )
     )
)
```